# Padding a numpy array with offsets for each data column

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm working with 2D numpy arrays which exhibit variable sizes, in terms of the number of rows and columns. I'd like to pad this array with zeros both before the start of the first row and at the end of the last row, but I'd like the start/end of the zeros to be offset in a different way for each column of data.

So the original 2D array:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

A Normal example of padding:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
0 0 0
```

Modified Padding with offsets (what I'm trying to do):

```
0 0 0
1 0 0 
4 0 3
7 2 6
0 5 9
0 8 0
```

Does numpy possess any functions which can replicate the last example in an extendable manner for variables numbers of rows/columns, that avoids the use of for loops/other computationally slow approaches?

Comment: My guess is that the best approach is to create the `zeros` target array, and copy columns one by one into the desired slot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a vectorized one with `broadcasting` and `boolean-indexing` -

```
def create_padded_array(a, row_start, n_rows):
    r = np.arange(n_rows)[:,None]
    row_start = np.asarray(row_start)
    mask = (r >= row_start) & (r < row_start+a.shape[0])

    out = np.zeros(mask.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
    out.T[mask.T] = a.ravel('F')
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [184]: a
Out[184]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [185]: create_padded_array(a, row_start=[1,3,2], n_rows=6)
Out[185]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 3],
       [7, 2, 6],
       [0, 5, 9],
       [0, 8, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the trouble, but I think I found the answer that I was looking for.

I can use numpy.pad to create an arbitrary number of filler zeros at the end of my original array. There is also a function called numpy.roll which can then be used to shift all array elements along a given axis by a set number of positions down the column.

After a quick test, it looks like this is extendable for an arbitrary number of matrix elements and allows a unique offset along each column.

Thanks to everyone for their responses to this question!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no such numpy function with those exact specific requirements, however what you can do is have your array:

`

```
In [10]: arr = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)])

In [11]: arr

Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])`
```

Then pad it:

```
In [12]: arr = np.pad(arr, ((2,1),(0,0)), 'constant', constant_values=(0))

In [13]: arr
Out[13]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Then you can randomize with shuffle (which I assume is what you want to do):
But np.random.shuffle only shuffles rows if this is satisfactory for your needs then:

```
In [14]: np.random.shuffle(arr)
In [15]: arr
Out[15]: 
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

If this is not satisfactory you can do this:

---

First create a 1D array:

```
In [16]: arr = np.arange(1,10)

In [17]: arr
Out[17]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Then pad your array with zeros:

```
In [18]: arr = np.pad(arr, (6,3), 'constant', constant_values = (0))

In [19]: arr
Out[19]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0])
```

Then you shuffle the array:

```
In [20]: np.random.shuffle(arr)

In [21]: arr
Out[21]: array([4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 7, 2, 1, 6, 0, 9])
```

Finally you reshape to the desired format:

```
In [22]: np.reshape(arr,[6,3])
Out[22]: 
array([[4, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 0],
       [7, 2, 1],
       [6, 0, 9]])
```

Although this may seem lengthy this is much quicker for large data sets than it will be using for loops, or any other python control structures. When you say offsets if you want to change the amount of randomness you can choose to only shuffle portions of the 1D array then combine it to the rest of the data so that way the whole data set is not shuffled but a portion you want to be shuffled is. 
(If what you mean by offsets is different from my assumption above please clarify in a comment)

Comment: `pad` is a complicated function because of its generality.  In some cases (may be all) it will iterate over the rows or columns.  So just because it hides the action, it doesn't mean that it is faster.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: this might complicate the solution, but I'm looking to do this with an offset that is specified for each individual column, rather than chosen at random. So to refer back to the original example, I might need to shift the first column of numbers by one row down, the second column by three rows down, and the final column by 2 rows down.

Comment: So for the non-zero terms, 1 should always be above 4 which should always be above 7, and all three should be in column 1 at all times. So on and so forth for columns 2 and 3.